# How to reroute simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm stuck. I want to create contact form on the main page of my application. So, the form on the main page looks like:

**app/views/main_page.html.slim**

```
 = simple_form_for(contact, url: contact_path) do |f|
    = f.input :name, label_html: { class: "modal__form-control" }
    = f.input :email, label_html: { class: "modal__form-control" }
    = f.input :phone, label_html: { class: "modal__form-control" }
    .modal__form-error
    = f.input :message, label_html: { class: "modal__form-control" }
```

As you see form: **contact, url: contact path**

Firstly, I've got an error Undefined variable contact, after it I added contact to **application_controller**.

Now I've got:
**undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass**

My controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:contact, attributes: :contact)

  def create
    ContactMailer.contact(contact).deliver_now if contact.save
    respond_with(contact, location: investors_path)
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:email, :message, :name, :phone)
  end
end
```

Expose is a [gem](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure)

Routing:

```
resource :contact, only: %i(new create)
```

Where I'm going wrong? I guess my application used wrong controller or can't find it(contact). How should I solve it?

UPD: added new method too.

Comment: What is `expose`? How/where is the `contact` variable being defined? And why are you defining a `new` route for `contract`, when there is no `new` action in `ContactsController`?

Comment: @TomLord expose https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure

Comment: @TomLord see update please

Comment: From where and how you are landing on `main_page`?

Comment: @Pavan main page has own pages controller. Route root to: "pages#main"

Comment: Please post that method from pages controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can either `expose(:contact)` from your `HomeController` or you can alter the form:

```
= simple_form_for(defined(:contact) ? contact : Contact.new) do |f|
```

Providing the path should not be needed as rails can figure it out with the polymorphic route helpers.